# Difference between shared hosting and PAAS?

Tags: web-hosting, shared-hosting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

They seem very similar. Are there important differences I should be aware of?

Comment: I've updated that question to include information on PaaS.

Answer (score 0):

Shared hosting is one server hosting multiple sites or resources.

"Platform as a service (PaaS) is a category of cloud computing services that provide a computing platform and a solution stack as a service." ~Wikipedia

They're actually the opposite.

Comment: Could you go into more detail on how they are opposite?

Comment: @AbeMiessler - Well, Shared hosting is putting multiple customers on one server. PaaS is putting one "resource" across an infrastructure, which utilizes multiple servers. The first is for economical efficiency in terms of the most utilization of hardware. The second is also efficient, but because it's very easily scalable.